# Website not working with SSL in IIS 10.0

Tags: ssl, iis, .net-framework

We have a wild card SSL certificate for domain.com from GoDaddy. Our main domain.com is hosted in Apache Server. Now, we have to host an application in IIS as a sub domain like staging.domain.com. I have added the .pfx file of the certificate in Personal folder through MMC and imported the same .pfx file in IIS Server Certificates and mapped that SSL certificate to staging.domain.com. While Http version of our new application is working fine, Https version is not working.

Where am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: _Where am I doing wrong?_ - you're not giving us any information, that's what you're doing wrong :-)  What domains are the certificate valid for?  What do you mean by _Https version is not working_? "Not working" is a very broad term indeed!

Comment: @garethTheRed, as i said, it is a multi domain certificate, which can be used for all the subdomains of domain.com. By the term Https Version, I meant, http: staging.domain.com is working and https: staging.domain.com is not working. By the term Not working, I meant, the site is not loading.

Comment: The term is _wildcard_ certificate - a _multi-domain_ certificate has a list of valid domains in the Subject Alternate Name extension (which is why I asked) while a _wildcard_ certificate is valid for all subdomains.  "Not loading" is still rather vague! Are there error messages displayed in your browser?  Anything in the server logs?

Comment: @garethTheRed, Oops!! My bad. It says, Server took too long to respond.

Comment: Can you access the site from the local server? If not, you've not bound the site to the certificate correctly.  If you can access the site from the server, but not remotely, check firewalls.

Comment: Https site is not loading in the local server as well. I tried disabling the firewall, but of no use.

Comment: Run `netstat -atn` on the local server.  In the output, you should see `TCP 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING InHost` and `TCP [::]:443 [::]:0  LISTENING InHost`.  This shows that IIS is listening on port 443.  If not, check your bindings again.

Comment: Yes, I am able to see both of them.